# How I can set env variable with value from expression in docker-compose after container start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  php-fpm:
    command: php-fpm --allow-to-run-as-root
    restart: always
    links:
      - postgresql
    build: ./php
    ports:
      - '9090:9000'
    volumes:
      - ../../:/var/www/html/
      - ./php/config/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    networks:
      - backend
```

And I want set environment variable with ip of php-fpm container to same container. For example if I call

```
docker exec -it php-fpm /bin/sh export ALLOWED_ID
```

I see my dynamic ip address of container 172.21.0.4 (for example)

I tried add to Dockerfile this code:

```
RUN export ALLOWED_ID=$(ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')
```

But it isn't work when I entrance to container.

I tried add sh command to docker-compose command section like this:

```
command: php-fpm --allow-to-run-as-root && export ALLOWED_ID=<some expression>
```

But it isn't correct syntax. Also I read about entrypoint sections in docker-compose file but I don't understand how it works and how to keep this "php-fpm --allow-to-run-as-root" code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty unusual to need to know a container's Docker-internal IP address.  Docker provides an internal DNS service where the name of each Docker Compose block resolves to that IP address; you can use the block names like `php-fpm` or `postgresql` as host names as normal (without a `links:` block; I would recommend removing it on general principle).

When Docker starts up, if the container has an entrypoint, it runs the entrypoint (only), passing the command (if any) as command-line arguments to it.  So a very typical path if you do need to do first-time setup like this is to write an entrypoint as a shell script that sets up environment variables and then runs the command it's given.  In your case this script could look like

```sh
#!/bin/sh
export ALLOWED_ID=$(ifconfig | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -v '127.0.0.1')
exec "$@"
```

(Assuming `ifconfig` is installed in your container; it's usually present, especially on Debian/Ubuntu based images, but rarely actually used.)

In your Dockerfile, at the same place you COPY in the application code, also COPY in this entrypoint script, and set it to be the image's default entrypoint (being careful to use the square-bracket form).

```
...
COPY . /var/www/html
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["php-fpm", "--allow-to-run-as-root"]
```

(Because this pattern is so useful, I tend to recommend defaulting to running the main container process as the CMD, so that you don't have to redesign everything if you do need to add an ENTRYPOINT wrapper.)

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I did like you wrote, create entrypoint.sh. Remove "command" from php-fpm service in docker-compose.yml.
But my ALLOWED_IP variable isn't accessible into my php-fpm container.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```sh
COPY entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
ENV ALLOWED_IP=${ALLOWED_IP}
```

and entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
export ALLOWED_IP="$(hostname -i)"
exec "$@"
```

And then if I run container

```sh
docker-compose run --rm php-fpm env
```

I see my ALLOWED_IP variable with container ip